# I want to zgrep from .debug.gz and get lines before and after the string

Tags: unix, awk, grep, aix

I'm logging in to my company's IBM AIX system and the `grep` there isn't GNU and it's the default one and it doesn't support the options `-B`, `-A`, `-C`. I found this workaround for normal `grep`:

```
grep -n '123456' file.debugz.gz |
cut -d':' -f1 |
xargs -n1 -I % awk 'NR<=%+3 && NR>=%-2' file.debugz.gz
```

However I'm trying to use `zgrep` or `zegrep` to get the values from inside a `.debug.gz` file which has a lot of data in it and big file size, so instead of `gunzip` and searching manually in each `.debug.gz` file I want to use the above command but it doesn't work with `zgrep` or `zegrep`.

I want to show a context of 30 lines above and below the matching line.

Please note that I cannot `gunzip` the file, I want to `grep` what's inside without any scripts or `gunzip`.

Comment: some zgrep's support `-c` option, which sends the output to stdout. If not, then you'll have to use `gunzip -c file | grep ...` which may complicates your `xarg... awk`. Good luck.

Comment: Use `zcat` piped to `GNU!grep`: `zcat bigfile.gz | /opt/freeware/bin/grep -A2 -B3 pattern`

Comment: That is a misunderstanding, `zgrep -c pattern file` means `zcat file.gz | grep -c pattern`

Comment: I tried this and worked but need to grep before and after. Gunzip -c file.debug.gz| grep -n 123456

Comment: Regarding "Please note that I cannot gunzip the file, I want to grep what's inside without any scripts or gunzip" - you can't. Text processing tools like `grep`, `sed`, and `awk` work on text files, a zip file is not a text file, you need something that understands the format of a zipped file such as `gunzip` or `zcat` to convert it to a text file before you can run a text processing tool on it.

Comment: @shellter your suggestion worked, but the xarg awk doesn't work afterwards idk why

Comment: **Edited** 1) What does one line of output look like, w/o the `xargs ...` section? 2) are there multiple lines of similar output? 3) Doesn't the solution below work as you need? 4) do you understand that `xargs` just "presents" the output from the pipe as arguments to the `awk` cmd (as if they were filenames)? Maybe using `set -vx` to debug, you will see how it works, and can then refashion the output (or input to awk) to work for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use awk to emulate the unsupported  `-A` / `-B` options (`-C` seems like a shortcut for specifying both).

For example:

- if required, store lines of input in a suitably-sized circular buffer
- when you find a match:

  - unless still printing a previous match, print appropriate "before" lines
  - set a counter for remaining lines to print
- if counter is positive:

  - print line
  - decrement counter

Optionally, keep track of when to print `--` divisions.

```
mygrep(){
    awk -v B=$1 -v A=$2 -v RE=$3 '
        $0~RE {
            if (!after) {
                if ( previous && (NR-B)-(previous+A)>1 )
                    print "--"
                for (before = (NR-B); before<NR; ++before)
                    if ( before > (previous+A) )
                        print buf[ before%B ]
            }
            after = A+1
            previous = NR
        }
        after { print; --after }
        +B { buf[ NR%B ] = $0 }
    '
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$ seq 100 | mygrep 1 2 '5[179]$'
50
51
52
53
--
56
57
58
59
60
61
$
```

You still need a way for awk to access the decompressed data. `gunzip -c` can write to stdout/pipe without unpacking the original file.

So you could do something like:

```
gunzip -c file.debug.gz | mygrep 30 30 '123456'
```